# What all outputs can I get if I type `/help` into a command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Recently, I tried typing `/help` in a command block. In the command block output it writes me some message like "Searge says: Ask for help on twitter". Always when I do this it shows me another message. I looked online for a complete list of outputs, but didn't find anything, just two or three /help outputs.

Could I get a complete list of possible outputs when typing /help in a command block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every output starts with "Searge says:" and then has one of the following:

- Contact helpdesk for help
- Sorry, no help today
- /testfornoob @p
- Oh my god, it's full of stats
- /kill @p[name=!Searge]
- /trigger warning
- Scoreboard deleted, commands blocked
- Ask for help on twitter
- Have you tried turning it off and on again?
- Yolo
- /deop @p
- /achievement take achievement.understandCommands @p